# jQuery doesn't find dom per class anymore after adding another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using client side validation for text fields that should only contain numbers.
I simply add a custom class *only-digits* to the specific model fields:

```
TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "k-textbox only-digits" })
```

..and process the users input as within a method:

```
$(".only-digits").keydown(function (e) {...}
```

This works fine but if an invalid form is posted back by the server, the .keydown event doesn't fire anymore.
I assume this is caused by the now added validation error class. The dom elements style is now:

```
input-validation-error k-textbox only-digits
```

Why does `$(".only-digits")` obviously not work anymore?

thx

Comment: Are you sure it's just adding classes, and not *replacing* the field with a new one? Sounds like an event delegation issue to me.

Comment: No I am not sure. Probably your're right. What's the solution here?

Comment: Please see my answer :)

Comment: Firstly look if the form post is AJAX post or normal post. If its an ajax POST and  partial view is returned as a result of validation errors, then the solution given by @BenM is correct. Otherwise there is something else which is going wrong and that should be looked for first instead for going directly for the solutions mentioned. Check your chrome console to see if there are any errors.
Maybe you should post your server validation code as well here so that we can see to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is an event delegation issue. To get around that, you need to bind the event to the closest static parent, and use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function as follows:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.only-digits', function(e) {  
    // Whatever code you need to run in your handler.
});
```

Please note that cluttering up `body` (or `document`) with delegated event handlers is generally bad practice. You will need to identify the closest static parent of all the `.only-digits` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `delegate` method if you want to use any selector which was created using script.
The `delegate` function can be used like following

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".only-digits", function(e){
    //your code goes here
})
```

Comment: `delegate()` is deprecated now, better to suggest using `on()`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @BenM, will surely consider using on() method.

Comment: @el_buck0 : I think you should accept BenM answer since he was quick and accurate